# Save baseball innings pitched decimal

Tags: python, django, database

I don’t really even know where to begin with this.

I have a Django form in which I am saving baseball stats to my database. The problem I an having is with innings pitched.

In baseball, innings are measured in thirds but instead of .33, .66, .99, each third is represented as .1, .2, .0

For example a pitcher could throw 5 innings, 5.1, 5.2, 6.

How can store and manipulate data this way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried strings?

Comment: I don't know a thing about baseball. Can you clarify how the counting is done? Would it be "0, 0.1, 0.2, 1, 1.1..." or "0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0..." or whatever?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille yes. 0.1, 0.2, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is probably to create two utility functions to convert the traditional notation to number of thirds, and vice versa.

```
def innings_to_thirds(score):
    score = float(score) #  we can accept floats or strings: 5.2 or "5.2"
    # 5.2 means 5 times 3 thirds ...
    thirds = 3 * int(score)
    # plus 0.2 * 10 = 2 thirds
    thirds += (score - int(score)) * 10 
    return int(thirds)

def thirds_to_innings(thirds):
    # the parts of the inning notation are the quotient 
    # and remainder of the division by 3
    q, r = divmod(thirds, 3)
    inning = str(q)
    if r:
        inning += '.' + str(r)
    return inning
```

Some tests:

```
innings = [0, "0.2", 1,  2.1, "2.2"]

for i in innings:
    print(f'{i} = {innings_to_thirds(i)} thirds')
    
thirds = [0, 2, 3, 7, 8]

for t in thirds:
    print(f'{t} thirds -> {thirds_to_innings(t)}')
```

Output:

```
0 = 0 thirds
0.2 = 2 thirds
1 = 3 thirds
2.1 = 7 thirds
2.2 = 8 thirds
0 thirds -> 0
2 thirds -> 0.2
3 thirds -> 1
7 thirds -> 2.1
8 thirds -> 2.2
```